# OpenMember After CloseMember

Tags: docusignapi

Our team would like the flexibility to re-Open Members accounts after we have closed them.  Business Case, user is deprovisioned therefore we will close the account.  User may come back therefore we would like to re-open that member.

Currently, we are creating members within our company account.

I've provided a link below to the CloseMember function.
http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Account%20Management%20Service%20API/CloseMembers.htm

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible through the DocuSign SOAP or REST APIs, you'll need to have an admin login to the DocuSign Console and re-open the user manually when needed.  Unfortunately enabling this through the APIs opens up some potential security issues related to account management.

To reopen closed members through the DocuSign Console you can do the following:

```
1.  Login to the Console (for production www.docusign.net, for testing demo.docusign.net)
2.  Click your profile icon in the top right of the screen.
3.  Select Preferences -> Users
4.  Click the "Show closed users" box if not clicked already.
5.  Click "Activate User" for any closed users you would like to reactivate.
```

Comment: Is it possible to pull a csv report of the individuals that have created an envelope for a given time period?  If we can't automate the account management, the next best thing is a manual batch activity. @Ergin

Comment: see above comment.  I forgot to tag you.

Comment: Please let me know if there are any questions on my above comment.

Comment: Maybe the Envelope Publish screen?  Login and go to Preferences -> Envelope Publish.  And please accept answer unless you have more questions...